# Circular layout dependencies

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.Filtros"
android:background="@drawable/fundo_ceu"
android:id="@+id/fundo">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Dormir"
    android:id="@+id/btnDormir"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="btnDormironClick"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnNatureza" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Info"
    android:id="@+id/btnInfo"
    android:onClick="btnInfoonClick"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnDormir"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnNatureza" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Comer"
    android:id="@+id/btnComer"
    android:onClick="btnComeronClick"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnDormir"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnDormir"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnDormir"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnNatureza" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bares"
    android:id="@+id/btnBar"
    android:onClick="btnBaronClick"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnComer"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnComer"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnComer"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnNatureza" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView11"
    android:src="@drawable/monumentos"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView11" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnInfo"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnInfo"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnInfo"
    android:src="@drawable/info" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnComer"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnDormir"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnDormir"
    android:src="@drawable/dormir" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Compras"
    android:id="@+id/btnCompras"
    android:onClick="btnComprasonClick"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnBar"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnBar"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnBar"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnNatureza" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnBar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnComer"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/btnComer"
    android:src="@drawable/comer" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnCompras"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnBar"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/btnBar"
    android:src="@drawable/bar" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnCompras"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnCompras"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnBar"
    android:src="@drawable/compras" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Natureza"
    android:id="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:onClick="btnPassearonClick"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView11" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:src="@drawable/passear"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnNatureza" />
```

I've got the circular dependencies error on my layout, ive tried to find any circular dependency but couldnt find it, anyone who sees?

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Comment: Can you post a graphical representation of your layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies in the following components

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Natureza"
    android:id="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:onClick="btnPassearonClick"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView11" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:src="@drawable/passear"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnNatureza" />
```

You specify that `btnNatureza` must be to the right of `imageView11` but then you tell `imageView11` that it must be to the left of `btnNatureza`. This is a circular dependancy since there is no starting point of reference for either view, they rely on each other to determine their position. In order to fix this you must remove either `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView11"` from the `Button` or `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnNatureza"` from the `ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

`btnNatureza` refers to `imageView2` which refers to `imageView11` which refers to `btnNatureza`

Also in general you can't say A is at the bottom of B and B is above A. Just keep one.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView11" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnNatureza"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnNatureza" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView11" />
```

Answer (score 0):

These two views reference each other

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Natureza"
android:id="@+id/btnNatureza"
android:onClick="btnPassearonClick"
android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView11"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView11" />

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imageView11"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnNatureza"
android:src="@drawable/passear"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnNatureza"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnNatureza" />
```